# Customize google-chart hAxis label

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using google-chart stacked BarChart with negative value. I would like to change the negative hAxis labels to positive dynamically without changing the actual values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can provide your own custom labels,
using the `ticks` option on the `hAxis`

using object notation, we can provide both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

```
{v: -8, f: '8.000'}
```

e.g.

```
hAxis: {
  format: '#,##0.000',
  ticks: [
    {v: -8, f: '8.000'},
    {v: -6, f: '6.000'},
    {v: -4, f: '4.000'},
    {v: -2, f: '2.000'},
    0, 2, 4, 6, 8
  ]
},
isStacked: true
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0', 'y1'],
    ['0-10', -3, 3],
    ['11-20', -2.5, 2.5],
    ['21-30', -2, 2],
    ['31-40', -1.5, 1.5],
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);

  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.000',
      ticks: [
        {v: -8, f: '8.000'},
        {v: -6, f: '6.000'},
        {v: -4, f: '4.000'},
        {v: -2, f: '2.000'},
        0, 2, 4, 6, 8
      ]
    },
    isStacked: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I would like the ticks to be generated dynamically and transform it into absolute number. The values would range from 50 to 1 million so its troublesome to do hard coding.

Comment: it can easily be done dynamically, above is just an example of how to accomplish. the range would come from the data used to draw the chart?

Comment: you can use data table method `getColumnRange(columnIndex)` to find the range of the axis